# Receive duplicate wsdl:binding and wsdl:service when accessing ?wsdl page

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf

I created a WSDL and exposed a web service as CXF endpoint at JBoss Fuse. I specified one wsdl:binding and one wsdl:service in the WSDL, but after deployed it to JBoss Fuse and accessed http://localhost:8081/PlaceOrderService?wsdl, I got duplicate wsdl:binding and wsdl:service. Anyone know why?

**WSDL - one wsdl:binding and wsdl:service**

```
<wsdl:message name="orderRecordRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="orderRecordInput" element="typens:orderRecordRequest" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="orderRecordResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="orderRecordOutput" element="typens:orderRecordResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="PlaceOrderService">
  <wsdl:operation name="OrderService">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:orderRecordRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:orderRecordResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="PlaceOrderServiceSOAPBinding" type="tns:PlaceOrderService">
  <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="OrderService">
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>    
<wsdl:service name="PlaceOrderService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PlaceOrderServiceSOAPBinding" name="PlaceOrderPort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/PlaceOrderService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

**`http://localhost:8081/PlaceOrderService?wsdl`
duplicate wsdl:binding and wsdl:service**

```
      <wsdl:binding name="PlaceOrderServiceSOAPBinding" type="tns:PlaceOrderService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="OrderService">
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="PlaceOrderServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:PlaceOrderService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="OrderService">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>  
    <wsdl:service name="PlaceOrderServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PlaceOrderServiceSoapBinding" name="PlaceOrderServicePort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/PlaceOrderService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>  
    <wsdl:service name="PlaceOrderService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PlaceOrderServiceSOAPBinding" name="PlaceOrderPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/PlaceOrderService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for that train, but for those with similar issues: note the different case in bindings name, make sure names in WSDL match names in generated Java classes.